# Make TextBlock fill ListView Row contents

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have the following XAML to populate a ListView Column.

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="Header" Header="MyHeader">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" Background ="Aquamarine" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                     </i:EventTrigger>
                 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
             </TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The problem is that the contents of the TextBlock do not fill the entire contents of the ListView row so if the user clicks outside the Aquamarine colour (The black area) the event does not fire (I'm using this colour to highlight where to click)

How can I get the TextBLock to fill the entire contents of the row?

[image]

Comment: Why not using a `DataGridTextColumn`?

Comment: Would this make a difference??

Comment: Give it a try. I never had your problems when using DataGridTextColumn?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? A DataGridTextColumn is used in a DataGrid and not in a GridView/ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` properties of the `ListView` to `Stretch` and use negative margins for the `TextBlock`:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="Header" Header="MyHeader">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                                       Background ="Aquamarine" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       Margin="-6 0 -6 0">
                                     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                         </i:EventTrigger>
                                     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```